# Where I can keep a draft

Tags: feature-request, editor

I need to make private drafts, so I can post a question after I have it chewed, clarified.

The question: Is here a way to make a draft, and keep it private?

If the answer is no, then I ask for that feature.
If the answer is yes, then I ask for a clear link towards drafts on the main page.

Comment: Use your personal computer to keep a draft. If you write across several computers, use your email to keep a draft.

Comment: But I want it on this website format. Nothing on my computer or e-mail supports stackexchange's $-tagged latex format, so I cannot copy-paste when I have the question ready for publication, and I cannot be sure how the text would work here. Sometimes I may need time to investigate the answer, and keeping a temporary text.

Comment: Copy to the answer box, see what you need to change, then copy it back to your personal notepad/email/word processor. If you have $\rm\LaTeX$, you can just edit your answer as a .tex document. If you haven't used anything non-standard, it should be easily transferable to the formatting here.

Comment: @ Asaf Karagila Should I take your comment as "there is not such a feature"?

Comment: [The sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4666/11619) might work for this purpose also, but A) there is nothing private about it, B) you should not hog it (I would say that you should not occupy more than one answer, and even that not for any extended period of time). Other than that I would recommend that you follow Asaf's suggestion, and possibly use the sandbox only to debug your MathJax.

Comment: @ Jyrki Lahtonen I do not understand what the sandbox is. Should I write my temporary text as an answer on that "question"? Should I just add the tag (sandbox) to a draft?. Is there a link to a sandbox (I cannot find where it is). If that is the answer, please, write it as an answer, so I can mark it as the answer to this question.

Comment: Does this help http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145100/draft-a-question ?

Comment: The site saves a draft automatically for a while. If it is just about one question this should usually work. If you'd want to save 20 drafts over months, this is not supported, and I don't think it should be.

Comment: Have a look at this post: [MathJax: better way to prepare a Math.StackExchange question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4735) The questions which are [linked there](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/4735) might be of interest, too.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Well,  [stackedit](https://stackedit.io/editor) (as suggested on your link) looks very helful!

Thanks for the tip.

Comment: [Allow questions to be saved as drafts prior to posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1177/230282)